# It keeps suspending just after waking up when lid is closed

Tags: suspend, wakeup, wakeonlan, lid

I have set my laptop having Ubuntu 16.04 to suspend when lid is closed. This is the behaviour I need.

In addition to that, I've also enabled wake-on-lan on the laptop, as I need to remotely access it sometimes.

Now, when I wake it up with WOL, it wakes up, I'm able to ssh, but it goes back to sleep soon after that. If I keep sending WOL packets, I can access it with interruptions, as it keeps suspending and waking up.

How do I fix this?

Comment: How long does the system take to suspend after waking it up?

Comment: ~25-30 seconds before the network disconnects after re-connection.

Comment: I'm sending WOL packet every second, doesn't help in keeping the system alive, but helps in waking it up once suspended.

Comment: Any idea how can I see the reasons or triggers for suspend and resume?